# How do if-else statements affect the return values of functions in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a simple question. I understand that, in Rust, functions generally return the last statement evaluated. However, if statements seem to complicate this. For example, this code will not compile:

```
fn return_numbere(number: u64) -> u64 {
    if (number > 40) {
        number + 1
    } 

    number - 1

}
```

However, if I add an else clause, it will compile:

```
fn return_numbere(number: u64) -> u64 {
    if (number > 40) {
        number + 1
    } else { 
      number - 1
      }

}
```

How do if-else statements change this idea of returning the last statement evaluated? Thanks, I have just begun learning Rust.

Comment: I don't know Rust at all, but I am 100% sure that this has nothing to do with the return value of the function. In your first example, the last expression that is evaluated (and thus the value that is returned) is *always* `number - 1` which evaluates to a `u64`, so the return type of the function is perfectly correct. In fact, the entire first 4 lines of the function don't do anything at all. I suspect it is the type of the conditional expression that is the problem, not the type of the function.

Comment: cause almost all is an expression in rust and so have a value.

Answer (score 2):

I have just found the answer after investigating further. Rust tells me that

```
 `if` expressions without `else` evaluate to `()`
  help: consider adding an `else` block that evaluates to the expected type
```

This is why I was getting  the cryptic error

```
expected `()`, found `u32`
```